# kafka connect task support multi format messages

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, fluentd

we are exploring fluentd, kafka and elasticsearch integration for our central logging platform.
at present we have individual topic for each deployments. for example if we have deployments customerA, `customerB, customerC` then we have separate topic on Kafka cluster for these deployments `customerA, customerB, customerC` .
as long as we push json logs to these topic our Elasticsearch sink connectors work fine but for log format other json tends to break connector task with error :

```
[2021-08-01 17:03:27,338] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=central-logs-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:475)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:229)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:239)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:366)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'status': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"status-task-central-logs-3"; line: 1, column: 8]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'status': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"status-task-central-logs-3"; line: 1, column: 8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:722)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3560)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2655)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:857)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:754)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4247)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2734)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:364)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:475)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:229)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:239)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

and our Elasticsearch sink connector config is :

```
{
   "name":"central-logs",
   "config":{
      "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
      "type.name":"_doc",
      "transforms.AddSuffix.topic.format":"${topic}-${timestamp}",
      "tasks.max":"16",
      "max.retries":"30",
      "retry.backoff.ms":"10000",
      "topics.regex": "kafka-(.*)",
      "transforms.ConvertTimestamp.format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
      "transforms":"AddSuffix,InsertTimestamp,ConvertTimestamp",
      "transforms.ConvertTimestamp.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
      "key.ignore":"true",
      "schema.ignore":"true",
      "transforms.AddSuffix.timestamp.format":"yyyy.MM.dd",
      "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
      "transforms.AddSuffix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter",
      "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
      "transforms.InsertTimestamp.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
      "name":"central-logs",
      "connection.url":"https://es",
      "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
      "transforms.InsertTimestamp.timestamp.field":"@timestamp",
      "transforms.ConvertTimestamp.target.type":"string",
      "read.timeout.ms":"30000",
      "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
      "transforms.ConvertTimestamp.field":"@timestamp"
   }
}
```

is there a way to avoid such connector/task failures?

Comment: The error says you got a message that is literally `'status'` which is not a JSON Object. You should consume `status-task-central-logs | grep status`, and see what the records actually look like

Comment: @OneCricketeer think below is the msg for which its failing:
```
{"message":"POST abc.net [status:200 request:0.017s]","file_name":"test-dummy-err.log","servername":"web","hostname":"abc.com","project":"test","env":"prod","service":"web","logVersion":1,"logLevel":"INFO","logType":"APP","requestId":"8ca9e474-0282-4663-8d38-4dc2753f95ba","processId":24389,"module":"base","name":"elasticsearch","timestamp":"2021-08-02T15:38:33Z","pathName":"/connection/base.py","fileName":"base.py","funcName":"log_request_success","lineNumber":228,"meta":{}}
```

Comment: `"message":"POST abc.net [status:200 request:0.017s]"` should be fine because its all part of the `"message"` value string...

Answer (score 0):

You have set the connector's converter to expect JSON:

> "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"

So any message in these topics which is not a valid JSON will fail when the JSON parser processes it. Is this parsing actually required? Looks like the ElasticSearch sink connector [example](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/blob/master/config/quickstart-elasticsearch.properties) does not do this.
Try removing this configuration.